# woody wouldn't have done this!

Tags: modal-verbs

> Lance: It is a total loss.
>
> Lance's son: How does this even happen?
>
> Woody Woodpecker (is hiding in the tree hole): I'm so sorry! I didn't
>   mean to!
>
> Fireman: Well, I think we found the cause of the fire. It looks like
>   something was destroying the wall and hit the wiring. It is probably a
>   small animal, mouse or a rat or a bird or something.
>
> Lance:Bird?Like a woodpecker?
>
> Fireman: That's possible.
>
> Lance's son: Dad, **woody wouldn't have done this!** It couldn't have been
>   him!
>
> Lance: Really?

1) Why did Lance's son use "would + have +p.p"? I think he could have said "Dad, woody didn't this".

It is a little bit confusing.

Movie: Woody Woodpecker

Answer (score 2):

"Didn't do this" means that Lance's son would be saying woody absolutely did not do it, and he has knowledge to say that definitively.

"Wouldn't have done this" is basically being a character witness. Lance's son means that he knows Woody well enough that he has the feeling that it wasn't him.

The difference between the two is that the former is a statement of fact (which Lance's son could not make unless he witnessed the "crime"), while the latter is a statement of opinion.

Comment: Thank you. what does this "which Woody's son could not make unless" mean? Woody is a bird.

Comment: @samsam whoops, meant to say lance's son. Edited

Answer (score 1):

We could argue about whether *He wouldn't have done / do that* is a "stronger" or a "weaker" assertion that *He didn't / doesn't do that*, but for most purposes it's just a stylistic choice which verb form to use.

Using the modal ***would*** rather than ***did*** (negated or not) could be seen as "distancing" the speaker from the assertion. So *I **would** think that's correct* sounds more "tentative" than *I think that's correct* - if only because it seems the speaker isn't even sure exactly what he *does* think. It's almost as if he's speculating what he *might* think - the implied hypothetical context being *...**if he were to give the matter his full consideration*** (which he hasn't yet, so it's just an initial reaction).

On the other hand, saying *He **wouldn't** do that* rather than *He **didn't** do that* could be seen as a *stronger* assertion, in that it tends to imply not only that he *didn't* do it, but that he would *never* do such a thing - the implied hypothetical context being *...**under any circumstances**.*

That second perspective certainly reflects the sense intended by Lance's son in the cited context, where *He wouldn't do that* is effectively equivalent to *He would **never** do that* (because it's simply not in his nature to do things like that).

Comment: +1 for "under any circumstances".

Comment: Thanks for your explanations and your time. But it seems that almost all of your explanations involve distinguishing between "would do" and "didn't do" while I needed to know the differences between "wouldn't have done " and "didn't do".

Comment: @samsam: In your specific context, using the "hypothetical present perfect" form ***wouldn't have done*** as opposed to "hypothetical present" (or "timeless") ***wouldn't do*** makes absolutely no difference to the meaning. As pointed out in my first sentence above, that's ***entirely*** a stylistic choice. I've devoted the rest of my answer to what should be more useful information for you - exploring why you might choose to introduce the conditional modal ***would*** at all - which is after all what you asked, with *Why **wouldn't have done*** rather than ***didn't**?*